# Kubernetes log not showing output of python print method

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes

I've a python application in which I'm using `print()` method tho show text to a user.  When I interact with this application manually using `kubectl exec ...` command I can see the output of prints.

However, when script is executed automatically on container startup with `CMD python3 /src/my_app.py` (last entry in `Dockerfile`) then, the prints are gone (not shown in `kubectl logs`). Ayn suggestin on how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This is because stdout and stderr streams are buffered in Python.

You can set the Environment variable to `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` or `True`

Also you could use [`-u`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u) option in your `Dockerfile`.

> `-u`
>
> Force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered. This option has no effect on the stdin stream.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: The text layer of the stdout and stderr streams now is unbuffered.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out to be a problem of python environment. Setting, these two environment variables `PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1` and `PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` fixed the issue.